# How to join these two pandas data frames?

Tags: python, join, dataframe, pandas

I am unable to join DataFrame1 with DataFrame2, I suspect this is due to one of them having an int64 index and the other having a string index. How do I convert the string index to an int64 one as well (if this is indeed the problem)? If not, how do I merge these two data frames?

DataFrame1

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9943 entries, 10029934 to 9962359
Data columns:
face_area     9943  non-null values
image_area    9943  non-null values
ratio         9943  non-null values
dtypes: int64(3)
```

DataFrame2

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 9412 entries, 10029934 to 9962359
Data columns:
1        9412  non-null values
2        9412  non-null values
name     9412  non-null values
class    9412  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
```

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?  Also, what is the nature of the actual values in the indices?  Does the second one just have the string versions of the indices in the first, or are they totally different?

Comment: I would be easier if you provided small sample `DataFrames` with the corresponding types and added the requested output.

Comment: @BrenBam Just found a solution, posted it below if you are curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataFrame2['id'] = DataFrame2.index.map(int)
DataFrame2.set_index('id')
```

This seems to have solved the problem and I am now able to join. If you have a more elegant solution, Id still love to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
```

Example:

```
In [1]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'])

In [2]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['c', 'd'], index=['0','1'])

In [3]: df2.index = df2.index.astype(int)

In [4]: df1.join(df2)
Out[4]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  1  2
1  3  4  3  4
```